# Excel: ranked/top text values in the range

Tags: excel

I have a single list of text values.
My task is to put the frequently used one in any cell:

```
DHL
FEDEX
FEDEX
UPS
DHL
FEDEX
```

So FEDEX is the top value in the list (seen 3 times).
If there is a tie, show the first in the alphabet or show both (ideally).

Thank you.

Comment: that's better done with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

If one has the dynamic array formula available with a subscription of Office 365, one can use:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MODE.MULT(MATCH($A$1:$A$6,A:A,0)))
```

[image]

in case of a tie it will spill down the list:

[image]

---

If not the add LARGE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,LARGE(MODE.MULT(MATCH($A$1:$A$7,A:A,0)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

This is an array formula and may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Then copy the formula down.

[image]

---

Note:

Both formula require that there be no blanks in the dataset.  We can deal with those by replacing the:

```
MATCH($A$1:$A$6,A:A,0)
```

In either formula with:

```
IFERROR(MATCH($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),A:A,0),FALSE))
```

This will now ignore blanks and is dynamic so as the list grows or shrinks it will do only the minimal iterations.

Comment: The only suggestion I would make is that instead of using "A:A" and "$A$1:$A$7", use a Table, so that as you add carriers, your range expands automatically.  If your data is in a Table with a column heading of "Carriers", you use =INDEX(Table1[Carriers],MODE.MULT(MATCH(Table1[Carriers],Table1[Carriers],0))).  Now if you add Carrier entry, your formula just keeps doing what your excellent post does.

Comment: @FrankBall see the latest edit.  I showed how to deal with that.

Comment: Nice.  I tend towards Tables because they give you so much benefit with the readability of formulas, automatic population of formulas and formatting, etc.  IMO, most people are really making their job harder by not utilizing Tables.

Comment: @FrankBall that is a preference thing, I hate tables and structured references and only use them when I want to do power pivot.  I personally find it harder to read the formula with structured references.

Comment: I love structured references! They help provide a measure of self documentation to your formulas.  When you have a really large table and you're trying to decipher the convoluted logic that someone is using, being able to read the formula as =(([Gross Profit]-[Annual Expenses])*[Profit Adjuster]*[Tax Rate])-[My Special Retirement Fund]) gives a user a much better understanding of what the formula is doing and not just what cells are referenced.

Comment: Thanks all. I must use a single cell for this solution because I have a huge table that has subtotals for every section I want to analyse. The above solution will be copied about 1000 times to return the carrier for each of the 1000 sections.

Comment: @PavloKobzar which version of Excel do you have?  Do you have TEXTJOIN?  If not then the only way is to use vba.

Comment: Can you use a pivot table for this?  It could only be set up to give you all carriers ranked according to frequency for reach section, but you would have visibility of the critical data. If needed, you could write a simple piece of VBA to extract just the top carriers.

Comment: @ScottCraner I do have TEXTJOIN. How would it help me here? I think I should just write a macro to add subtotals and the above formula for every subtotal section. The example subtotal line for every section would read "product name" | "qty shipped" [sum] | "most used courier" [your formula]

Comment: Your question is starting to creep.  To show ties in the same cell you would wrap the formula in TEXTJOIN.

Comment: Hello, Please help to tweak the very first formula for the case when the range is just one line/cell! I automated that formula with VBA (using integers and iCol) to be distributed for every section of my range and it is working fine, except for when the range to INDEX is just one cell - I just need that cell's value. Thanks!